# pgfplotstable: read gnuplot generated table and typeset

Tags: pgfplotstable, gnuplot

I am new to [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable), I am trying to read [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/) exported table in `pgfplotstable`.

gnuplot script:

```
set samples 91
set table "file.dat"
set angles degrees
plot [0:90] sin(x),cos(x),tan(x);
unset table
```

gnuplot table `file.dat` is given below (5 points given to be concise):

```
# Curve 0 of 3, 91 points
# Curve title: "sin(x)"
# x y type
 0  0  i
 1  0.0174524  i
 2  0.0348995  i
 3  0.052336  i
 4  0.0697565  i
 5  0.0871557  i

# Curve 1 of 3, 91 points
# Curve title: "cos(x)"
# x y type
 0  1  i
 1  0.999848  i
 2  0.999391  i
 3  0.99863  i
 4  0.997564  i
 5  0.996195  i

# Curve 2 of 3, 91 points
# Curve title: "tan(x)"
# x y type
 0  0  i
 1  0.0174551  i
 2  0.0349208  i
 3  0.0524078  i
 4  0.0699268  i
 5  0.0874887  i
```

Note: It's possible to read table header and format (all data arranged in columns) given below compared to the above case (all data arranged sequentially)

```
# A B C 
  1 2 3 
  4 5 7
  8 9 10
```

**Question**

Is it possible to read custom format ASCII file in `pgfplotstable` by `\pgfplotstableset{}` or any other workarounds in gnuplot to make it read well and typeset in `pgfplotstable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially I thought you wanted to plot the data but reading your question again it seems you just want to set it as a table using `pgfplotstable` you can do something like this although I'm not sure `pgfplotstable` is really helping in this case, by the time you've re-arranged the data to be read by `\pgfplotstabletypeset` you could simply write it as a `longtable`, 
however...

[image]

[update for non integer first column]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,longtable,array}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\loopb#1\repeatb{\def\iterateb{#1\relax\expandafter\iterateb\fi}%
  \iterateb \let\iterateb\relax}
\let\repeatb\fi

\begingroup

\count@\z@
\catcode`\#12
\catcode`\*=6

\def\tstrelax{\relax}
\def\tsti{i}

\def\ca*1# Curve*2 of *3,*4 points*5!!{%
  \def\cnum{*2}\def\ctot{*3}\def\cpoints{*4}}

\def\cb*1# Curve title: "*2"*3!!{%
  \def\title{*2}}

\def\cc*1 *2 *3 *4!!{%
\def\x{*1}\def\y{*2}\def\ci{*3}}

\newread\myin
\openin\myin=file.dat

\@tempcnta\z@

\loop
\ifeof\myin\else
\read\myin to \tmp
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\par\tmp
\else
  \expandafter\cb\tmp# Curve title: "\relax"!!%
  \ifx\title\tstrelax
    \expandafter\ca\tmp# Curve of \relax, points!!%
    \ifx\ctot\tstrelax
      \expandafter\cc\tmp. . . !!%
      \ifx\ci\tsti
        \expandafter\edef\csname my-\the\@tempcnta-\the\@tempcntb\endcsname{\ifnum\@tempcnta=1 \x\space\fi\y}
        \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
 \fi
    \else
      \let\total\ctot
      \let\points\cpoints
      \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
      \@tempcntb\z@
    \fi
  \else
    \expandafter\let\csname my-\the\@tempcnta-title\endcsname\title
  \fi
\fi
\repeat

{\let\\\relax

\gdef\mytable{}
\gdef\row{x}
\@tempcnta\z@
\loop
\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
\xdef\row{\row\space \csname my-\the\@tempcnta-title\endcsname}
\ifnum\@tempcnta<\total
\repeat
\xdef\mytable{\row\space\\\space}

\@tempcntb\z@
\loopb
\xdef\row{}
\@tempcnta\z@
\loop
\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
\xdef\row{\row\space \csname my-\the\@tempcnta-\the\@tempcntb\endcsname}
\ifnum\@tempcnta<\total
\repeat
\xdef\mytable{\mytable\row\space\\\space}
\advance\@tempcntb\@ne
\ifnum\@tempcntb<\points
\repeatb

\show\mytable
\xdef\tmp{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[row sep=\noexpand\\, begin table=\noexpand\begin{longtable}, 
end table=\noexpand\end{longtable}
sci,precision=5]{\mytable}}
}



\endgroup

\tmp

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to extend on Eg: # Curve 2 of 6(`data_sets`), 991(`numb_pnts`) points to typeset with five significant digits after decimal ?

Comment: @texenthusiast changing the end of the code to `sci,precision=5]{\mytable}` does something

Answer (score 1):

Although not a great low level TeX answer like above, surprisingly overlooked previously and found today that using pgfplotstable options [`ignore chars={\i}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79982/15717) to read full `gnuplot` table `file.dat` in two columns and [`select equal part entry of`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103461/15717) to rearrange two columns into equal rows of 3 columns. But could not find pgfplotstable options to read multiple headers("sin(x)","cos(x)" and "tan(x)") automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pgfplotstableset{begin table=\begin{longtable},end table=\end{longtable},%
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},%
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},%
every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{.8}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={0,1,1,1},%
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},column name=$x$},%
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},column name=$sin(x)$},%
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},column name=$cos(x)$},%
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},column name=$tan(x)$},%
precision=5,ignore chars={\i}]{file.dat}
\end{document}
```